# Join two tables using join

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables as below. I would like to keep everything from t1 and everything from t2 except Date,Id. The metrics value (Salary,Bonus) for both tables should not be changed.  As there are multiple date and id in t1, I am getting duplicate in the output. My code is as below.Please assist.

select t1.*,t2.*except(Date,Id) from t1
left join t2
on t1.Date = t2. Date
and t1.Id= t2.Id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMXsq.png)

Comment: There is no way to do this in BigQuery AFAIK other than to list out the columns from the second table which you do want to include.

Comment: @ Tim, How do I list out the columns

Answer (score 0):

While the logic for your output table might be lacking of explanation, I can answer your main question. You can use [LEFT JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#left_outer_join) and simply manually [SELECT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_) all the columns you desired from each table, writing them in the desired order.

Below is the syntax for that with some sample data I created.

```
with t1 as (
SELECT DATE(2020,01,22) as Date, 1 as id, "abc" as Name, "NYC" as City, "USA" as Country, 5000 as Salary UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2020,01,23) as Date, 2 as id, "abc" as Name, "SF" as City, "USA" as Country, 8000 as Salary UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2020,01,22) as Date, 2 as id, "abc" as Name, "SF" as City, "USA" as Country, 8000 as Salary
), 
t2 as (
SELECT DATE(2020,01,22) as Date, 1 as id, "Man" as Position, "1st" as Rank, 1000 as Bonus UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2020,01,22) as Date, 2 as id, "Man" as Position, "1st" as Rank, 1000 as Bonus
)
SELECT t1.Date, t1.id, t1.Name, t1.City, t2.Position, t2.Rank, t1.Country, t1.Salary, 
         t2.Bonus  
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.Date=t2.Date and t1.id=t2.id
```

And the output,

[image]

Notice that I have selected the columns in the order I wanted them to be in the output. Furthermore, `Date` and `id` come from table 1 as specified in the select statement. Another important point is that where  `t1.Date=t2.Date and t1.id=t2.id`  are not checked as true, the values assigned to the columns from `t2` are `null`.

*I would like to point that I have set manually the value for the `Rank` column just as a sample. Lastly, everything within `with()` is sample data.*